# Float, Boolean , double are classes or primitive data types, in java..?

Tags: java

Float, Boolean , double are classes or primitive data types, in java..?
If they are classes, even String also a class, is that not a primitive data type.?

Comment: We're happy to help with programming questions. We're not here to do basic documentation searches for you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: See our documentation - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/148/primitive-data-types#t=201610141722452524037

Comment: The ones with capital letters are classes that wrap a single primitive type. They are used for situations where you need an object, such as putting them into a list, like ``List<Integer>``.

Answer (score 0):

The classes like `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` are called wrappers around the primitive types - `int`, `float`, `double`. `String` is a completely different class and not a primitive type, and not connected in any way to a primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Java primitive types are clearly defined in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html) and in the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

You can identify them easily since their names begin lowercase but wrappers not
example

**float** (primitive) and **Float** (Wrapper)

Others are more or less intuitive to identify:

**int** (primitive) and **Integer** (Wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

The only primitive data types in java are
byte
int
long
float
double
boolean
char

The rest are classes, like
Integer
Double
Float
String

Answer (score -1):

`int`, `float`, `double` are primitive data types in java. But `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` are wrapper classes in java. If you want to create an object and do some methods, then you can use this class.
Ex:

```
Integer num = new Integer(25);
num.floatValue();
```

And you don't want to import this class because this class inside java.lang package